# Can we use any builtin methods are function to convert a banded matrix A to Ab form. Is there any function are method in NumPy/SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

I came across a [Github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8362) where a function was implemented to convert a banded matrix into Ab form, however, I want a "smarter" way like built-in methods or functions to convert to Ab. I am searching to find it inside the NumPy or SciPy. I think these library missing this.?

I have searched NumPy and SciPy documentation but failed to find such methods and functions.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained and with a [mre]. What you want is currently highly unclear.

Answer (score 0):

No. The code snippet in the linked issue looks reasonable. Has not been added to either scipy or numpy, and is, frankly, unlikely to be. So just reuse it.

Comment: Glad to see your response, however i wanted to make sure, that why not NumPy and SciPy have methods/ function for such task?